# As a root user, I do not have permission to create/write any file in any directory

Tags: linux, permissions, certificates

As a root user, I cannot create/edit any file in any directory all of a sudden with the following error.

```
E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Everything was working fine. The last thing I did was to create a conf file on the /etc/rsyslog.d directory and remove it afterward since it was a useless one. Can it be related to that? How can I solve this?

Comment: can you create this filename by hand, without using certtool?

Comment: no. I realized that I do not have permission to create/edit any file anymore for some reason.

Comment: You should update the question with the new findings. Add what's the error message (eg: Read-only file system etc.), if you have any relevant kernel logs etc. And probably remove any ref to certtool.

Comment: when I try to create a file with touch, it says no space left on device

Comment: Seems you found the problem. Maybe your deleted conf for logs is still used and logs too much?

Comment: Yes, I've found out that there was no disk space left due to the high amount of logs... thank you for helping me.